# Not decrypting what I have encrypted

Tags: python, encryption

I am having an issue with my decryption algorithm. It outputs to a text file a huge list of repeated ((((( and other things. What's wrong with my code, and how can I fix it? I think it has something to do with the last function of the decrypting process. But I am not sure.

```
    import sys
    import os.path
    def convertToNum(ch):
        alpha ='''abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890`~!@#$%^&()-_=+[]{}\\|;:\'",./<>?\n\t '''
        index = alpha.find(ch)
    return index

def Matrix(text):
    evenChars = []
    oddChars = [] 
    index = 0

    for ch in text:        
        if index % 2 == 0:
        #this is an even character
            evenChars.append(convertToNum(ch))
        else: #this is an odd character
            oddChars.append(convertToNum(ch))

     index += 1
masterList = []
    if (evenChars >(oddChars)):
        oddChars.append(convertToNum(" "))    
    for i in range(len(evenChars)):
        masterList.append([evenChars[i],oddChars[i]])

    return masterList

def getMatrices(text):
    print("A list of integers acts as a key. Each value is stored in a,b,c,d. Please enter the values for: ")
    a = int(input("\nA :"))
    b = int(input("B :"))
    c = int(input("C :"))
    d = int(input("D :"))

    if (a*d) - (c*b) == 1:
        print("Valid Key\n")
    elif (a*d) - (c*b) ==-1:
        print("Valid Key\n")
    else:
        print("Invalid Key")
        sys.exit()

    indList = Matrix(text)
    encryptList = []
    for nestList in indList:
        x = nestList[0]
        y = nestList[1]
        encryptList.append(x*a + y*c) 
        encryptList.append(x*b + y*d)
    return encryptList

def backtoText(text):
    print("A list of integers acts as a key. Each value is stored in a,b,c,d. If you have already entered a key to encrypt, please use the same key. Please enter the values for: ")
    a = int(input("\nA :"))
    b = int(input("B :"))
    c = int(input("C :"))
    d = int(input("D :"))

    if (a*d) - (c*b) == 1:
        print("Valid Key\n")
    elif (a*d) - (c*b) ==-1:
        print("Valid Key\n")
    else:
        print("Invalid Key") 
        sys.exit()

    keyA = ((a*d) - (c*b)) * (d)
    keyB = ((a*d) - (c*b)) * (-b)
    keyC = ((a*d) - (c*b)) * (-c)
    keyD = ((a*d) - (c*b)) * (a)

    print(keyA,keyB,keyC,keyD)

    evenNums=[]
    oddNums=[]
    index = 0

    for ch in text:        #ch takes the place of the next characer in plain text
        if index % 2 == 0:
            evenNums.append(ch)
         else:
            oddNums.append(ch)

        index += 1    

    decrypted= []
    if (evenNums >(oddNums)):
         oddNums.append(" ")    
    for i in range(len(evenNums)):
         decrypted.append([evenNums[i],oddNums[i]])    

    indList = decrypted
    decryptList = []
    for nestList in indList:
        x = nestList[0]
        y = nestList[1]
        decryptList.append(x*keyA + y*keyC) 
        decryptList.append(x*keyB + y*keyD)
    return decryptList

def outPutString(text):
    alpha = '''abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}\\|;:\'",./<>?\n\t ''' 
    finalString =''
    text = backtoText(text)
    for ch in text:
        finalString += alpha[ch]
    return finalString

def main():
    print("What would you like to do?: ")
    answer = input("1) Encrypt File\n2) Decrypt File\n\n")
    if answer == '1':
        fileName = input("Please enter a filename to encrypt : ")
        if not os.path.isfile(fileName):
            print("Invalid Entry. Computer will self destruct in 10 seconds\n\n")
             sys.exit()

        plaintext_file = open(fileName)
        text = ""
        for line in plaintext_file.readlines():
             text += line + "\n"

        plaintext_file.close()
        name =input("Please enter the file name that you want to save the encrypted file as : ")
        if os.path.isfile(name) == False:
            matrices = getMatrices(text)
            for value in matrices:
                encrypted_file.write(str(value) + "\n")
            encrypted_file.close()
            encrypted_file.write(str(getMatrices(text)))
            encrypted_file.close()

        elif os.path.isfile(name) == True:
            answer2 = input("The file already exists. Would you like to overwrite it? >> Type y/n >> ")
            if answer2 == 'y':
                encrypted_file = open(name,'w')
                encrypted_file.write(str(getMatrices(text)))
                encrypted_file.close()

            elif answer == 'n':
                print("Thank you for wasting time :D \n\n") 
                sys.exit()
            else:
                print("Invalid response. It's not hard to put y or n.\n\n") 
                sys.exit()

    elif answer == '2':
        fileName = input("Please enter a filename to decrypt : ")
        if not os.path.isfile(fileName):
            print("Invalid Entry. Computer will self destruct in 10 seconds\n\n")
            sys.exit()

        Encrypted_file = open(fileName)
        text = []
        for line in Encrypted_file.readlines():
            text.append(line)

        Encrypted_file.close()
        name = input("Please enter the file name that you want to save the decrypted text saved as : ")
        if os.path.isfile(name) == False:
            Decrypted_file = open(name,'w')
            Decrypted_file.write(str(outPutString(text)))
            Decrypted_file.close()                    

        elif os.path.isfile(name) == True:           
            answer2 = input("The file already exists. Would you like to overwrite it? >> Type y/n >> ")
            if answer2 == 'y':
                Decrypted_file = open(name,'w')
                Decrypted_file.write(str(outPutString(text)))
                Decrypted_file.close()                        
            elif answer == 'n':
                print("Thank you for wasting time :D \n\n") 
                sys.exit()
            else:
                print("Invalid response. It's not hard to put y or n.\n\n") 
                sys.exit()

    else:
        print("Invalid Entry. The program will terminate")
        sys.exit()
 main()
```

Comment: You can make it potential answerers much easier (which directly leads to more/better answers) if you describe what algorithm this is supposed to be, show example inputs, their outputs and what outputs you expected. You can [edit] you question to include those details.

Comment: if (evenChars >(oddChars)): doesn't do what you think...

Comment: What is the expected output and what do you see?

Comment: Thank you all for commenting and helping me out. This is the firs time I have posted something to Stack Overflow and I greatly appreciate the feedback. Also, for the one that posted the code below that fixed the program, I owe you. Thank you so much for explaining the easy things I had to do. I couldn't be happier. You guys made my day. Have a good one!

Answer (score 1):

Well this was a fun one!

in `def convertToNum(ch):` the `alpha` does not equal the `alpha` in `def outPutString(text):` (missing an *) causing (in my case) tabs instead of spaces and a ? to appear at the end of my decrypted string. I would recommend using a global variable to prevent things like this happening in the future.

Your encryption algorithm worked great and didn't need any adjustment. There were some incompatible variable types in the decryption phase but I managed to get everything to work and have included the working code (my comments marked with `##`) I hope this helped.

Edit: As Eric points out in the comments, `if (evenNum>(oddNum))` is probably not doing what you want it to do. According to the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types):

> Sequence objects may be compared to other objects with the same sequence type. The comparison uses lexicographical ordering: first the first two items are compared, and if they differ this determines the outcome of the comparison; if they are equal, the next two items are compared, and so on, until either sequence is exhausted.

I *Assume* you want to compare the lengths of the two arrays to make sure they are equal. If this is the case then you would want to use `if (len(evenNum)>len(oddNum))`

```
import sys
import os.path
def convertToNum(ch):
    alpha ='''abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}\\|;:\'",./<>?\n\t ''' #you forgot your asterix
    index = alpha.find(ch)
    return index

def Matrix(text):
    evenChars = []
    oddChars = [] 
    index = 0

    for ch in text:        
        if index % 2 == 0:
        #this is an even character
            evenChars.append(convertToNum(ch))
        else: #this is an odd character
            oddChars.append(convertToNum(ch))
        index += 1

    masterList = []
    if (len(evenChars) >len(oddChars)): ## comparing lengths instead of contents
        oddChars.append(convertToNum(" "))    
    for i in range(len(evenChars)):
        masterList.append([evenChars[i],oddChars[i]])

    return masterList

def getMatrices(text):
    print("A list of integers acts as a key. Each value is stored in a,b,c,d. Please enter the values for: ")
    a = int(input("\nA :"))
    b = int(input("B :"))
    c = int(input("C :"))
    d = int(input("D :"))

    if (a*d) - (c*b) == 1:
        print("Valid Key\n")
    elif (a*d) - (c*b) ==-1:
        print("Valid Key\n")
    else:
        print("Invalid Key")
        sys.exit()

    indList = Matrix(text)
    encryptList = []
    for nestList in indList:
        x = nestList[0]
        y = nestList[1]
        encryptList.append(x*a + y*c) 
        encryptList.append(x*b + y*d)
    return encryptList

def backtoText(text):
    print("A list of integers acts as a key. Each value is stored in a,b,c,d. If you have already entered a key to encrypt, please use the same key. Please enter the values for: ")
    a = int(input("\nA :"))
    b = int(input("B :"))
    c = int(input("C :"))
    d = int(input("D :"))

    if (a*d) - (c*b) == 1:
        print("Valid Key\n")
    elif (a*d) - (c*b) ==-1:
        print("Valid Key\n")
    else:
        print("Invalid Key") 
        sys.exit()

    keyA = ((a*d) - (c*b)) * (d)
    keyB = ((a*d) - (c*b)) * (-b)
    keyC = ((a*d) - (c*b)) * (-c)
    keyD = ((a*d) - (c*b)) * (a)

    print(keyA,keyB,keyC,keyD)

    evenNums=[]
    oddNums=[]
    index = 0
    newText = text[0].strip('[ ]') ## these two lines convert the string to an array
    textArray = newText.split(',')

    for ch in textArray:        ## changed text to textArray(see above) #ch takes the place of the next characer in plain text
        if index % 2 == 0:
            evenNums.append(int(ch)) ## converting string number to int for later operations
        else:
            oddNums.append(int(ch))

        index += 1

    decrypted= []
    if (len(evenNums) >len(oddNums)): ## comparing lengths instead of arrays
         oddNums.append(" ")    
    for i in range(len(evenNums)):
         decrypted.append([evenNums[i],oddNums[i]])    

    indList = decrypted
    decryptList = []
    for nestList in indList:
        x = nestList[0]
        y = nestList[1]
        decryptList.append(x*keyA + y*keyC) 
        decryptList.append(x*keyB + y*keyD)
    return decryptList

def outPutString(text):
    alpha = '''abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}\\|;:\'",./<>?\n\t '''
    finalString =''
    text = backtoText(text)
    for ch in text:
        finalString += alpha[ch]
    print(finalString)
    return finalString

def main():
    print("What would you like to do?: ")
    answer = input("1) Encrypt File\n2) Decrypt File\n\n")
    if answer == '1':
        fileName = input("Please enter a filename to encrypt : ")
        if not os.path.isfile(fileName):
            print("Invalid Entry. Computer will self destruct in 10 seconds\n\n")
            sys.exit()

        plaintext_file = open(fileName)
        text = ""
        for line in plaintext_file.readlines():
            text += line ##+ "\n" ##you don't need to add a new line as '\n' is already included at the end of every line.

        plaintext_file.close()
        name =input("Please enter the file name that you want to save the encrypted file as : ")
        if os.path.isfile(name) == False:
            ##matrices = getMatrices(text) 
            ##for value in matrices:
                ##encrypted_file.write(str(value) + "\n")
            ##encrypted_file.close()
            ## I added the line below(and removed lines above) to be consistent with your later usage
            encrypted_file = open(name,'w')  
            encrypted_file.write(str(getMatrices(text)))
            encrypted_file.close()

        elif os.path.isfile(name) == True:
            answer2 = input("The file already exists. Would you like to overwrite it? >> Type y/n >> ")
            if answer2 == 'y':
                encrypted_file = open(name,'w')
                encrypted_file.write(str(getMatrices(text)))
                encrypted_file.close()

            elif answer == 'n':
                print("Thank you for wasting time :D \n\n") 
                sys.exit()
            else:
                print("Invalid response. It's not hard to put y or n.\n\n") 
                sys.exit()

    elif answer == '2':
        fileName = input("Please enter a filename to decrypt : ")
        if not os.path.isfile(fileName):
            print("Invalid Entry. Computer will self destruct in 10 seconds\n\n")
            sys.exit()

        Encrypted_file = open(fileName)
        text = []
        for line in Encrypted_file.readlines():
            text.append(line)

        Encrypted_file.close()
        name = input("Please enter the file name that you want to save the decrypted text saved as : ")
        if os.path.isfile(name) == False:
            Decrypted_file = open(name,'w')
            Decrypted_file.write(str(outPutString(text)))
            Decrypted_file.close()                    

        elif os.path.isfile(name) == True:           
            answer2 = input("The file already exists. Would you like to overwrite it? >> Type y/n >> ")
            if answer2 == 'y':
                Decrypted_file = open(name,'w')
                Decrypted_file.write(str(outPutString(text)))
                Decrypted_file.close()                        
            elif answer == 'n':
                print("Thank you for wasting time :D \n\n") 
                sys.exit()
            else:
                print("Invalid response. It's not hard to put y or n.\n\n") 
                sys.exit()

    else:
        print("Invalid Entry. The program will terminate")
        sys.exit()
main()
```

Comment: P.S. I used Key A:3 B:2 C:5 D:3

Comment: You should use my comment on the question...

Comment: P.P.S. I would highly recommend _Hacking Secret Ciphers with Python_ by Al Sweigart for anyone interested in learning python basics through codes and encryptions. It is available free online here [link](https://inventwithpython.com/hacking/index.html)

Comment: good point @EricLevieil I included your comment in the answer.